# Select com data retornando vazio

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde,
 O que poderia estar errado em minha query que esta retornando vazio por causa da condição da data.
 Segue query:

```
   SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondola    AS GONDOLA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  imp_estoque_dc AS EST_DC,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NECFAT,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao  WHERE imp_data =  NOW() 
       ORDER BY imp_desc
```

Segue a tabela:

```
# Host: localhost  (Version 5.5.5-10.1.13-MariaDB)
# Date: 2016-06-23 15:57:02
# Generator: MySQL-Front 5.3  (Build 5.33)

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

#
# Structure for table "importacao"
#

CREATE TABLE `importacao` (
  `imp_loja` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_item` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_desc` varchar(254) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_obs` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_dias_venda` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_dias_giro` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_nec` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_pedido` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_bancao` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_romaneio` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_transito` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_gondola` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_fator` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_reposicao` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_estoque` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_estoque_dc` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imp_data` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

#
# Data for table "importacao"
#
```

Obs:
 Já tentei:

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
CURDATE()
NOW()
```

Comment: Provavelmente o a hora/minuto do `now()` não deve bater o valor armazenado, se for comparar apenas a data, faça um cast para date de ambos os valores. Só confirme se precisa data ou data e hora.

Comment: rray, não conheço o casta poderia me dar um exemplo , por favor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se for comparar apenas a data, faça um cast em ambos os valores para fazer a comparação 'na medida correta'.

A atual comparação seria algo como: `WHERE '2016-06-26 12:00:01' =  '2016-06-26 17:03:34'`, quando deveria ser `WHERE '2016-06-26' = '2016-06-26'`

Mude:

```
WHERE imp_data =  NOW()
```

Para:

```
WHERE cast(imp_data as date) =  cast(NOW() as date)
```

Comment: perfeito,desconhecia o cast. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O problema deve estar no fato de você comparar seu campo `imp_data` com `NOW`, que representa a **data/hora atual**.

Se deseja listar os registros com `imp_data` igual a **data atual**, use `CURDATE` no lugar de `NOW`. Assim:

```
SELECT  
  imp_loja       AS LOJA,
  imp_item       AS ITEM,
  imp_desc       AS DESCRICAO,
  imp_dias_giro  AS DIAS_DE_GIRO,
  imp_nec        AS NECESSIDADE,
  imp_pedido     AS PEDIDO,
  imp_bancao     AS BANCAO,
  imp_romaneio   AS ROMANEIO, 
  imp_transito   AS TRANSITO,
  imp_gondola    AS GONDOLA,
  imp_fator      AS FATOR,
  imp_reposicao  AS REPOSICAO,
  imp_estoque    AS ESTOQUE,
  imp_estoque_dc AS EST_DC,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NEC_FAT,
  (imp_estoque / imp_fator) AS EXT_X_FATOR,
  (imp_estoque + imp_transito) AS ESTTRAN,
  (imp_nec - imp_fator) AS NECFAT,
  imp_data       AS DATA
  FROM importacao  WHERE DATE(imp_data) =  CURDATE() 
       ORDER BY imp_desc
```

Além disso, você deve **extrair a parte de data** do seu campo para comparação com a função `DATE()`.

Comment: coloquei no complemento da observação,também esta retornando vazio.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, faça um teste...

Comment: Já pontuei,perfeito também obrigado.